# Is there a way to reduce the spacing between the Action Item Icons on Action Bar?

Tags: android

I wanted to reduce the spacing bettween Action Item icons added to the ActionBar. Is there a way we can do this?

Comment: The top answer seems pretty good to me - is there a reason it hasn't been accepted?

Answer (score 69):

use a custom android:actionButtonStyle.

```
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
```

and the magic is here:

```
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>                  
</style>
```

normaly minWidth is set to 56 dip.

Comment: Not workig for me in API level 11. Working in API levels 14+.

Comment: To work with older API, we must also set <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>

Comment: note that setting android:minWidth to 0 causes crashes when long-pressing edittext in some situations. (on some popular devices like the SGSII)

Comment: Does the default minWidth of 56 dp apply to all drawable versions?

Comment: If not working put in different folders like put in values-v21, values-v17 (if these folder exist) put in these folder's style.xml also

Comment: How to use that on Toolbar?

Comment: im confused as to where to put `<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>` ?

Comment: Is it possible to apply this to a single item?

Comment: It does not worked for me without  <item name="android:maxWidth">30dp</item>

Comment: This way works even for material toolbar

Answer (score 17):

For SDK versions 17+ you should use paddingStart and paddingEnd properties, if you have minSdkVersion < 17 you must use different styles for each version, like this:

**res/values/styles.xml :**

```
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>

<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>                  
</style>
```

**res/values-v17/styles.xml :**

```
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>

<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dip</item>                  
</style>
```

Comment: This should be the correct approach for overriding padding for 17+ devices. Thanks.

Comment: This one worked for me! In case this helps, I added `<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>` just once inside my `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` element of `res/values/styles.xml`. Then added the `<style name="ActionButtonStyle" ...` versions in both `styles.xml` files. Android will pick the correct definition of `@style/ActionButtonStyle` depending on the platform version.

Comment: To correct my previous comment: I actually added `<item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>` (in the default `styles.xml` and `<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">` in both `styles.xml` (default and v17). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211328/1121497).

Comment: It does not worked for me without  <item name="android:maxWidth">30dp</item>

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to Shai for his hint, that works pretty well for me (on an Android 4.0.x device):
(my whole style.xml)

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.

    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 12):

For supporting older version using appCompat you need nothing but this:

In your application's appTheme :

```
<item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
```

and create a style
in **style.xml**

```
 <!--this will reduce space between actionBar Icons-->
    <style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">50dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
    </style>
```

That's it. You are done.

Comment: To make it work in v17 and above I also added the `res/values-v17/styles.xml` version with `paddingStart` and `paddingEnd` as [pedroca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25410775/1121497) suggests.

Comment: The secret is the <item name="android:maxWidth">30dp</item>

Answer (score 5):

In appTheme add

```
<item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/CustomActionButtonStyle</item>
```

and then in style.xml create this style

```
<style name="CustomActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:paddingStart">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dip</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find that this is hard-to-impossible to accomplish without getting extremely hackish or just creating your own custom ActionBar.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254476/android-3-0-cannot-style-action-bar-s-action-item-buttons) for what seems like a pretty similar question.  I did some testing myself overriding android:actionButtonStyle, and while I was able to override certain things (like the background), it refused to honor any kind of padding attributes i specified.

Comment: Thanks for the link Hankystyles, I tried to override android:actionButtonStyle , however was not able to change the background too. Here is how i am doing it.
'code'(<style name="customactionbuttonstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/selectableitem_selector</item>
 </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">     
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/customactionbuttonstyle</item>
 </style>)
'code'
Then i tried overriding android:selectableItemBackground that dint work either.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me. So I wrapped the icon in a drawable xml using layer-list and give it a negative left margin, and it worked for me this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="-20dp">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/actionbar_logo"
            android:gravity="left" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom ActionBar, you can add custom spacing, between elements, if you want to move items closer to each other, you can use negative values for your attributes.  Like this pseudo-code (in your layout xml file):

```
<ImageView 
android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
```