# Android how can I create this thin gaps between buttons?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Take a look at action bar at this famous app.
How can I create this thin gaps between buttons?

[image]

Comment: you can use either margin or padding to do this....

Answer (score 1):

try in your xml the addtributes `android:padding` and `android:margin` when using a `TableLayout` or a `GridLayout`

Answer (score 0):

In Android this Dashboard User Interface . please check out the [link](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/build-dashboard-ui-for-android/)

I think it help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file that contains your buttons, specify android:layout_marginLeft / android:layout_marginRight (for the buttons) according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

first of all the source code of the [IOschede application is open source](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) so you can easily take a look inside it and understand how it works.

by the way here is a description of the problem and wich solution you can take, of course it all depends on whic is you `minSdk` attribute.

**Android 3.0> with native ActionBar**

if are talking about the native 3.0> ActionBar then take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131954/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-spacing-between-the-action-item-icons-on-action-bar) question.

you can use this attribute in your application style.

`<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>`

and define the style here and place a custom 9patch background with a left vertical stripe

```
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_bg</item>             
</style>
```

**Android <3.0**

you can either decide tu use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and solve all yours compatibility problem or take a look at the *IOsched* solution, if i'm not wrong they take the buttons style the same way it works for the native ActionBar with a application Theme attribute .

Comment: I`m using  ActionBarSherlock. But I do not see any way to paste separators between buttons.

Comment: in [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/styled/res/values/styles.xml) saple shows how to customize the action bar. In particular there are `actionBarItemBackground` and `android:actionBarItemBackground` that are both setted to a drawbale... so using the right drawable you can achive what you are looking to do.
By the way, i haven't tried but, i think that the method i decribed for 3.0> works also with ActionBarSherlock.