# How to change actionBar icon size?

Tags: android

The actionBar icon should like 
[image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16455237/ab1.png)[image]

When the device resolution is 1920x1080 and android 4.2 above, the icon size looks very small:
[image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16455237/ab2.png)[image]

(android 4.1 is correct)

My problem seems like [i-want-to-change-actionbar-icon-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299508/i-want-to-change-actionbar-icon-size).

The icon image size is 113x40, then I use getActionBar().getHeight() to get ActionBar height is 56.

menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_buyer"
    android:icon="@drawable/buyer_bts"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_exhibition_bt"
    android:icon="@drawable/exhibition_bt"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_oj"
    android:icon="@drawable/download_bt"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

I tried following method but doesn't work:

1. create bigger icon image (ex.170x60) then put into drawable-hdpi(xhdpi, xxhdpi...etc.) folder
2. use menu.findItem(R.id.menu_buyer).setIcon(resizeImage(int resId, int w, int h)); to resize icon
3. added a style < item name="android:actionBarSize" > 200dp < /item > in style.xml
   then set theme in Manifest file

Is there a way can show the icon correctly?

Answer (score 9):

Too late to answer but, I found the answer

It's quite simple.
First, convert drawable into a bitmap, resize it and re-convert into drawable. Then get the item of the menu and set the icon as the new drawable.

Please add this re-size method on your activity as follow.

```
private Bitmap resizeBitmapImageFn(
        Bitmap bmpSource, int maxResolution){
    int iWidth = bmpSource.getWidth();
    int iHeight = bmpSource.getHeight();
    int newWidth = iWidth ;
    int newHeight = iHeight ;
    float rate = 0.0f;

    if(iWidth > iHeight ){
        if(maxResolution < iWidth ){
            rate = maxResolution / (float) iWidth ;
            newHeight = (int) (iHeight * rate);
            newWidth = maxResolution;
        }
    }else{
        if(maxResolution < iHeight ){
            rate = maxResolution / (float) iHeight ;
            newWidth = (int) (iWidth * rate);
            newHeight = maxResolution;
        }
    }

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            bmpSource, newWidth, newHeight, true);
}
```

and add the work in the onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer); //Converting drawable into bitmap
    Bitmap new_icon = resizeBitmapImageFn(icon, 50); //resizing the bitmap
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),new_icon); //Converting bitmap into drawable
    menu.getItem(0).setIcon(d); //choose the item number you want to set
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's working great. Thanks! (Android 8.1 Oreo). However I would recommend you [store the bitmap locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location) to avoid calling this method on every activity which uses the actionbar

Answer (score 0):

Please keep maintaining image with sizes and resolution . Like:

```
- drawable-ldpi (it need resolution or ppi is ~120)(keep small size image)
 - drawable-mdpi (it need resolution or ppi is ~160)(keep normal size image)
 - drawable-hdpi (it need resolution or ppi is ~240)(keep larger size image)
 - drawable-xhdpi (it need resolution or ppi is ~320)(keep xlarger size image)
```

You can also study this reference link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html