# android: change icon size

Tags: android, icons, toolbar

I try to finish my `Toolbar`, but the icon size of whatever icon I use is a bit too large in comparison to the "settings"-dots as well as the search icon in my `Toolbar`.
I tried to change the size manually with GIMP, however Android Studio still scales up the icons to the previous size.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Here is my XML for the menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_notification_white"
    android:id="@+id/sv_toolbar_main"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"
    />

<item
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_main_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_add_notifier"
    android:title="notifications"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:orderInCategory="1"/>

</menu>
```

and here is my relevant onCreate code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

In onCreateOptionsMenu I only made changes to the searchView in the toolbar:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        mSearchViewToolbar = menu.findItem(R.id.sv_toolbar_main);
        SearchView searchViewAction = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSearchViewToolbar);
        searchViewAction.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchViewAction.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchViewAction.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                cursorFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(arg0) ? arg0 : null;
                getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(ID_LOADER_MAIN, null, MainActivity.this);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

how can i adjust the size of an icon or increase the size of the other icons?

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679320/how-to-change-android-top-toolbar-menu-item-icon-size

Comment: can't find a solution for my problem there though

Comment: I was thinking creating a custom layout with top/bottom margins would work. Another solution could be adding margins to the icon itself with GIMP. As a last solution, you can make a custom toolbar and have more control by using an ImagveView.

Comment: thanks man! I used the GIMP workaround