# Android actionbar back button custom and resize

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-drawable

I change in style.xml

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back</item>
```

It change back.png but size is too big.

How I can resize this icon on actionbar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299508/i-want-to-change-actionbar-icon-size

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks but this link is for actionbar button not for back button I think.

Comment: Do what i have mentioned in my answer, It works for me @PolarisNation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Website to Convert Images](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=0&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&crop=0&backgroundShape=none&effects=none&name=ic_launcher) in different sizes eg. `hdpi`,`mdpi`,`xhdpi` etc.

And put you converted images inside **mipmap** folder

**Reference Code :**

```
  Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
    TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    mTitle.setText("Open Docket");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_back_appbar);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but is there any method to resize home button image?

Comment: What you are using image size is too big, so you have to convert the same image in 5 different sizes and use that image.

Comment: Yes I follow link and resize it and put it mdpi size but it is too big

Comment: can you show me the Toolbar xml code ? @PolarisNation

Comment: Thanks and I resize it and done. It occurs because of Magnification.

Comment: Welcome @PolarisNation

Answer (score 0):

you can use the customtool bar like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_gray">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
        <com.rg.goals.utils.customstyles.TextViewSemibold
            android:id="@+id/txtview_toolbartext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/round_icon"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <com.rg.goals.utils.customstyles.TextViewRegular
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewShare"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/share"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```