# TextView in Sherlock action bar

Tags: java, android

I have an app where I want to display the current chapter number in the action bar (sherlock). My menu.xml looks like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:title=""/>

</menu>
```

I am getting NullPointerException when using the following code:

```
titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
titleView.setText(chapterno);
```

Any idea, how can we show text in sherlock action bar and update it dynamically.

The ActionBar looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a custom layout in the action bar and not a menu item to achieve this.

in `onCreate()`

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_number);
```

Your layout should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginMedium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_number"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

To update the number:

```
TextView chapterNumber = (TextView) getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
chapterNumber.setText(String.valueOf(number));
```

**UPDATE**
To add menu action item you should be able to do that as normal, just be careful, the positioning of your custom layout may overlap menu items or hide then if they appear in the action bar.

in `menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/share"
        android:visible="false"/>

</menu>
```

Then in your activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
    ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider(); //line 387

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");

    shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        break;

    case R.id.menu_share:
        // EXAMPLE OF WHAT YOU CAN DO
        //          Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //          sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
        //          sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
        //          //sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        //          //sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
        //          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

        break;

    default:
        break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: And how would I add action items to this customized action bar. Like for share action, I simply add     <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share"/> to my menu.xml and then inflate this xml in the onCreateOptionsMenu method

Comment: You should be able to create that as you create share actions. please see updated answer.

Comment: This is working great. But the problem which this chapter no. text has created is that the logo is not visible now. Though there is a lot of padding between the action items. I tried reducing padding as mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131954/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-spacing-between-the-action-item-icons-on-action-bar but that didn't work out. Any pointers. The action bar image is there in my post.

Comment: Which logo is no longer appearing? The spacing is what it is between the action intent and your other items, one thing you can do is make your icons for the menu larger! Or generally play with the padding around each icon, I've had this issue before and I solved it with a little trial and error. The link is correct as far as removing the padding and margin goes I would remove the padding and margins and just add the padding to my icon image. `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` should show the icon, though by default it should be visible.

Comment: yes I am talking about the app icon. Once I am using, DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM, the icon has disappeared. I removed some of the action icons and confirmed that it is not due to space. The 0dip padding  and setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true) also don't help. Do I need to modify my custom layout and include one imageview and textview with imageview showing ic_launcher and textview showing the current chapter no.?

Comment: No, I've never had this problem try this `mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);` I left out `DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME` in my example but it may be what you need.

Comment: DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME works for me. But it was causing the icon to go small. Right now I have gone for custom view with ImageView for icon and TextView for chapter name. Thanks a lot for your help Ali.

Comment: There is a demo app for the Sherlock Action Bar on Google Play, you should be able to download it's corresponding code from Jake Whartons GitHub account and see how to do everything.