# Set Spacing Between Action Item Icons Programmatically / Dynamically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, padding

According to the link below, they show how to control the
spacing/padding between Action Item Icons in xml.

However, the spacing is fixed and not flexible enough to me. Is it possible for me to set the padding dynamically / programmatically? 
Many thanks in advance.

@style/ActionButtonStyle
and the magic is here:

0dip
    0dip
    0dip

normaly minWidth is set to 56 dip.

[Is there a way to reduce the spacing between the Action Item Icons on Action Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131954/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-spacing-between-the-action-item-icons-on-action-bar)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.base_menu, menu);
            toolbar.getChildAt(3); //ActionMenuView

        }
```

**Please note:** The position depends on number of views you have in toolbar and after you can easily control the measurements by setting your custom `Toolbar.LayoutParams`