# How to prevent app title in action bar from being cut off?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

Right now the title of my app in the actionbar can be a maximum of 12 characters before it gets cut off to 10 characters and an ellipsis. The name of my app is 16 characters long. How can I have the full name displayed? All I have in the app bar is the app name, a spinner, one menu item, and the overflow menu. It seems like there's enough space for everything to fit. Is there some way to stop the name from being cut off or change the spacing between items on the action bar? I could move one of the menu items into the overflow but would prefer not to since there seems to be enough space for everything.

My code:

in  `OnCreate()`:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

OnCreateOptionsMenu():

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item); // get the spinner

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.countries, R.layout.spinner_layout);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    return true;
}
```

My menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:title="Country"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/spinner">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:title="Refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_autorenew_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        >

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="About App">

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings">

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="Share">

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:title="Rate App">

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:title="Contact Us ">

    </item>

</menu>
```

My toolbar:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I figured it out, you can reduce the spacing using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131954/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-spacing-between-the-action-item-icons-on-action-bar